# Getting Drive ID from Teams returning Error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm having an issue getting a Drive ID when making a GET request.

First I'm creating the Team using "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams". The request returns no response but a Status 202 accepted, the new Team is listed on Teams. I then extract the Team ID from Response Headers "Location".

Here is the failure, I make a request to [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{{TeamsID}}/drive](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7B%7BTeamsID%7D%7D/drive)

Here is my response back

```
{"error":{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"Resource is not found.","innerError":{"date":"2021-05-03T19:17:03","request-id":"75b4888d-de91-41aa-89ef-d983fcb5238d","client-request-id":"75b4888d-de91-41aa-89ef-d983fcb5238d"}}}
```

I make the same request on via postman and it works fine.

Here is my code

```
try {
        let crt = await createTeam(msalData, data);
        crt.headers.forEach( async (val, key) => {
            if (key === "location") {
                let id = val.split("/teams('")[1].split("')/operations")[0];
                let gdd = await getDocumentDrive(msalData, id);
                console.log(gdd)
            }
        });
            
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I wont making all at the same call itself - as the location or the all the attributes wont be set when you try to create the teams, so i would do this differently(just similar to POSTMAN how it works) to see if it helps.. (1) Create the Teams programmatically (2) Make sure its created (3) then i will go ahead, make the call to get the location info to see location is available.

Comment: @Dev I've just noticed when I create the team it takes 30 seconds to a minute so the ID can be actively used. A work around I used was to create the Team, then keep calling the get the drive api "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{{TeamsID}}/drive" until a successful response is returned. This works until the api is updated.

Comment: Exactly that was i said above... immediately dont try the resource and not in the same call itself, try it after a while. Glad to hear that it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the error (`ResourceNotFound`) occurs since the moment when [`Get Drive` request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) is submitted the Group *is not yet completely provisioned*, [documentations says the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-put-teams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) in this regard:

> If the group was created less than 15 minutes ago, it's possible for
> the Create team call to fail with a 404 error code due to replication
> delays. The recommended pattern is to retry the Create team call three
> times, with a 10 second delay between calls.

Since you haven't revealed how exactly `createTeam` function is implemented, [retry pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/retry) come to the rescue here, for example:

```
async function withRetry(fn, maxRetry = 5, ms = 1000) {
  try {
    const val = await fn();
    return val;
  } catch (error) {
    if (maxRetry) {
      await new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
      return withRetry(fn, maxRetry - 1, ms);
    } else throw new Error(`Max retries reached for function ${fn.name}`);
  }
}
```

and now Teams could be *created* like this (note, in retry logic [Get `Group` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) request is submitted to ensure it has been provisioned):

```
async function ensureTeam(client, teamName, defaultOwnerId) {
  const teamResp = await createTeam(client, teamName, defaultOwnerId);
  const teamloc = teamResp.headers.get("Content-Location");
  return await withRetry(
    async () => {
      const groupUrl = teamloc.replace("teams", "groups");
      return await client.api(groupUrl).get();
    },
    5,
    10000
  );
}
```

where `createTeam` could look like this:

```
async function createTeam(client, teamName, defaultOwnerId) {
  const team = {
    "template@odata.bind":
      "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teamsTemplates('standard')",
    displayName: teamName,
    description: teamName,
    members: [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
        roles: ["owner"],
        "user@odata.bind": `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('${defaultOwnerId}')`,
      },
    ],
  };

  return await client.api("/teams").responseType(ResponseType.RAW).post(team);
}
```

**Usage**

```
const graphClient = Client.initWithMiddleware({ authProvider });
const group = await ensureTeam(graphClient,"Demo team",ownerId);
const driveUrl = `/groups/${group.id}/drive`;
const drive = await graphClient.api(driveUrl).get();
```